# can not find web element using webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to find elements on below URL to perform some task, but I could not found any element on this page. So, kindly help me.

URL: https://cdns.webex.com/mw3000/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=cdns

My code is:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[7]/span/a"));
System.out.println(element.getAttribute("id"));
```

Error which I faced :

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element.
```

Comment: Which particular elements you are trying to find?

Comment: @Sam - please dig in and try to use a better locator strategy for WebElements on a page.

Answer (score 0):

The page you specified is made up of multiple [frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame). The element you are searching for is inside one of the frames. I'm not particularly familiar with Selenium, so I don't know if it supports going across frame boundaries like that, but that's where you need to start looking at least.